# Xcode thinks my currently selected device is my Apple Watch, but it isn't

Tags: xcode

I have previously run my app on my iPhone--I know the provisioning file is fine.

For some reason, I am now currently having a weird problem where xCode *thinks* I'm trying to run my app on my Apple Watch. Because of this problem, I get errors that prevent me from building or running the app on my phone. (The simulator still works fine though.)

Specifically, the errors are:

`Provisioning profile <name of my provisioning file> doesn't include the currently selected device <my Apple Watch's name>`

and

`Code signing is required for product type 'Application' in SDK 'iOS 10.2'`

This issue happened to me a bit earlier, and then it somehow went away...it's not going away this time though. Any hacky thoughts on how to get around this problem? Thanks!

EDIT: Also, I've never built an app for the Apple Watch and I've never registered as one of my devices or connected it to my Mac.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's what works every time:

Put Apple Watch in airplane mode. Then disconnect iPhone from computer and re-plug in. Works every time! Seems to be a weird bug Apple needs to fix.

Comment: Glad this was finally helpful to someone besides myself! :)